# Abrir ou form1 ou form2 na inicializacao do programa winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-basic-6

tenho um programa em vb6 e possui dois botoes - Uma mara scanner e outro para consulta de imagens escaneadas.
Criei um programa em c# winform em que no projeto tem 2 forms - um form1 para o scanner e outro form2 para as consultas das imagens scaneadas. Os dois no .Net funcionam perfeitamente. Gostaria de saber se existe como fazer com que ao executar o programa .net , através de um parametro 1 ou 2 , escolher qual dos forms irão executar atravéz do VB6

No vb pretendo dependendo do botão clicado, ira gravar em uma tabela ou 1 ou 2 . No botão escolhido, ira chamar a aplicação atraves do shell.
Iniciando a aplicação, consultarei a tabelacom o parametro escolhido e abrirei o form solicitado.

Só não sei como fazer isso no .net c#.
o inicio do Program.cs esta assim no .net

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    ConsultaImagens2 f2 = new ConsultaImagens2();
    Application.Run(f2);
    MainFrame f1 = new MainFrame();
    f1.Close();

    MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
    ConsultaImagens mf = new ConsultaImagens();
    Application.Run(mf);
    MainFrame mf1 = new MainFrame();
    mf1.Close();
}
```

Comment: Você quer que o usuário escolha qual aplicação (form1 ou form2) executar, ao abrir o programa? você pode criar um novo **form** com opções e um botão que ira checar essas opções e abrir o respectivo programa,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, isso é completamente possível. Para isso você pode usar os parâmetros no método `Main`. Como você vai chamar o executável pelo prompt, é só fazer

> **C:\AlgumaPasta > nomeAplicacao.exe ConsultaImagens2**

O código fica mais ou menos assim:

Obs: Não entendi porque instanciar aquele `MainFrame` então o removi.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Form formAbrir;

    if(args[1] == "ConsultaImagens2") //a posição 0 é sempre o caminho do arquivo
        formAbrir = new ConsultaImgens2();
    else
        formAbrir = new ConsultaImagens();

    Application.Run(formAbrir);
}
```

Comment: Para um dos botões estou colocando a seguinte rotina em shell, e ao rodar só abre o form  ConsultaImagens :   Como segue    "ShellExecute Me.hwnd, "open", "C:/ScannerSefaz_V08/EscaneamentoSefaz.exe " & ConsultaImagens2 & " ", "C:/", "C:/", vbNormalFocus" Passei parametros para args  e esta abrindo corretamente no c#

Comment: Então tem algo errado na passagem de parâmetros

Comment: Esta sintaxe esta correta ou devo trocar? ShellExecute Me.hwnd, "open", "C:/ScannerSefaz_V08/EscaneamentoSefaz.exe " & ConsultaImagens2 & " ", "C:/", "C:/", vbNormalFocus" ?

Comment: Perfeito JBueno, deu certo. eu só estava dando espaco em branco no shelll. Ja corrigi                     ShellExecute Me.hwnd, "open", "C:/ScannerSefaz_V08/Consulta/ConsultaEsc", "C:/", "C:/", vbNormalFocus